# Python TCP socket returns getaddrinfo failed when using Ngrok

Tags: python, sockets, ngrok, pyngrok

I'm trying to use Ngrok to connect two python scripts using the `socket` module. I've tried doing this with the ngrok.exe and with pyngrok. Trying to connect with the client using `port` as `12345` or `80` (everything else times out).

On the client `s.connect((ip, port))` doesn't error, but the Python server.py and the ngrok terminal don't register anything. The URL definitely works as Ngrok registers a `502 bad gateway` when I put the URL into a web browser.

I assume this is because the sockets aren't using HTTP, instead TCP, but when I start Ngrok with a TCP flag (`ngrok.exe TCP 12345`) the forwarding address looks like `tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:xxxxx` which when I put this into the client  `socket.connect()` it returns `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

So I guess my question is, how to get the Python client socket to accept this address or should I be doing something different?

Thanks

server.py

```
from pyngrok import ngrok
import socket

port = 12345

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', port))

public_url = ngrok.connect(port)
print("ngrok tunnel \"{}\" -> \"http://127.0.0.1:{}/\"".format(public_url, port))

s.listen(5)      
print("socket is listening" )

c, addr = s.accept()

print('Got connection from', addr )

c.send(str.encode(str("Yes")))

while True:
    c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
url = "copied from server or ngrok"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(url)
port = 12345
s.connect((ip, 12345))
```

Comment: gethostbyname expects a **hostname** and not some URL. This is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname). The name you need to use is the domain part from the URL and then you need to use the port from the URL to connect.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to click the checkmark on answers to the benefit community members that helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of `pyngrok`, which I see that you are using. There is actually a TCP socket/client integration example in the documentation, which can be found [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#python-tcp-server-and-client).

But you're on the right track. The short of it is, you're not specifying a protocol, which means the default one (`http`) is being used. You need to tell `pyngrok` and `ngrok` that you want to setup a `tcp` tunnel. So instead do this:

```
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(port, "tcp", remote_addr="{}:{}".format(host, port))
print("ngrok tunnel \"{}\" -> \"tcp://127.0.0.1:{}/\"".format(ngrok_tunnel.public_url, port))
```

For the `host` and `port`, you'll need to have first setup a `ngrok` subdomain ( you can do that [here](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/endpoints/domains)), something like `host="1.tcp.ngrok.io"`. Then you pass that same host/post to your `client.py` as well (what you're doing wrong there is including the protocol `tcp://`, leave that off).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another example of secure Python sockets using ngrok.
You can design your code ignoring ngrok and then inject pyngrok dependency (couple of lines) after testing.

##### ssl_client.py

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys, os, select, socket

def verify_cb(conn, cert, errnum, depth, ok):
    # This obviously has to be updated
    print ('Got certificate: %s' % cert.get_subject())
    return ok

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print ('Usage: python[2] client.py HOST PORT')
    sys.exit(1)

dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
if dir == '':
    dir = os.curdir

# Initialize context
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb) # Demand a certificate
ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'simple','client.pkey'))
ctx.use_certificate_file(os.path.join(dir, 'simple','client.cert'))
ctx.load_verify_locations(os.path.join(dir, 'simple','CA.cert'))

# Set up client
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))

while 1:

    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    try:
        sock.send(line.encode())
    except SSL.Error:
        raise
        print ('Connection died unexpectedly')
        break


sock.shutdown()
sock.close()
```

##### ssl_server.py

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys, os, select, socket


def verify_cb(conn, cert, errnum, depth, ok):
    # This obviously has to be updated
    print ('Got certificate: %s' % cert.get_subject())
    return ok

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print ('Usage: python[2] server.py PORT')
    sys.exit(1)

dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
if dir == '':
    dir = os.curdir

# Initialize context
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER|SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_cb) # Demand a certificate
ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'simple', 'server.pkey'))
ctx.use_certificate_file(os.path.join(dir, 'simple', 'server.cert'))
ctx.load_verify_locations(os.path.join(dir, 'simple', 'CA.cert'))

# Set up server
server = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
server.bind(('', int(sys.argv[1])))
server.listen(3) 
server.setblocking(0)

clients = {}
writers = {}

def dropClient(cli, errors=None):
    if errors:
        print ('Client %s left unexpectedly:' % (clients[cli],))
        print ('  ', errors)
    else:
        print ('Client %s left politely' % (clients[cli],))
    del clients[cli]
    if cli in writers:
        del writers[cli]
    if not errors:
        cli.shutdown()
    cli.close()
from pyngrok import ngrok

port=6063 #make a param
public_url = ngrok.connect(port, "tcp").public_url
print(f"ngrok tunnel '{public_url}' -> 'tcp://127.0.0.1:{port}'")

while 1:

    try:
        r,w,_ = select.select([server]+list(clients.keys()), writers.keys(), [])
    except:
        
        raise

    for cli in r:
        if cli == server:
            cli,addr = server.accept()
            print ('Connection from %s' % (addr,))
            clients[cli] = addr

        else:
            try:
                ret = cli.recv(1024)
                print(555, ret)
            except (SSL.WantReadError, SSL.WantWriteError, SSL.WantX509LookupError):
                pass
            except SSL.ZeroReturnError:
                raise
                dropClient(cli)
            except SSL.Error as errors:
                raise
                dropClient(cli, errors)
            else:
                if not cli in writers:
                    writers[cli] = b''
                writers[cli] = writers[cli] + ret
    if 0:
        for cli in w:
            try:
                ret = cli.send(writers[cli])
            except (SSL.WantReadError, SSL.WantWriteError, SSL.WantX509LookupError):
                pass
            except SSL.ZeroReturnError:
                print(111)
                raise
                dropClient(cli)
            except SSL.Error as  errors:
                raise
                dropClient(cli, errors)
            else:
                writers[cli] = writers[cli][ret:]
                if writers[cli] == '':
                    del writers[cli]

for cli in clients.keys():
    cli.close()
server.close()
```

URL change at line #59

Details are here: [secure-python-socket-using-ngrok](https://github.com/pydemo/secure-python-socket-using-ngrok)